# Why my Task.ContinueWith not wait the define time

Tags: c#, task

I am using this method to open specific work with concurrent Threads from my Main UI thread:

```
    private List<MyData> MyCollection;
    private static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

        private void Start()
        {
            int concurrentThread = (int)nudConcurrentFiles.Value;
            int loops = (int)nudLoops.Value;
            var token = _tokenSource.Token;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    while (Iteration.LoopFinished < loops)
                    {
                        Parallel.ForEach(PcapList.Files,
                        new ParallelOptions
                        {
                            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = concurrentThread //limit number of parallel threads 
                        },
                        File=>
                        {
                            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                                return;
                            //do work...
                        });

                        Iteration.LoopFinished++;

                        Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(
                           t =>
                           {

                           }, _tokenSource.Token);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                { }

            }, _tokenSource.Token,
           TaskCreationOptions.None,
           TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(
                t =>
                {

                }
            );
        }
```

The problem is that after loop i want to wait 10 secons and `Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith` not waiting this 10 seconds but start immedietly another loop.

Comment: Move the delay out of the loop?

Comment: But i want to wait between loops

Comment: Use await Task.Delay inside the loop

Comment: no.method must be async. @Sievajet

Comment: `Tak.Delay(10000).Wait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in order to execute the task

```
Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(
t =>
{
}, _tokenSource.Token).Wait();
```